# Usar una variable de un método en otro archivo

Tags: php, html

Estoy creando un monedero con html y php y guardo los datos en un txt.
Necesito que cada vez que lea cada apunte al escribirlo en la tabla me sume el importe y debajo de la tabla me ponga el total.
La suma la hago en un método que está en el archivo de la clase, pero fuera de ella, y la variable total la quiero llamar en el index.
Estos son los dos archivos que tengo.
monedero.php (ver el método listado_registros):

```
<?php
    function boton_ficticio($caption,$url){
        return "<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=3 bgcolor=black>
            <tr><td bgcolor=\"green\">
                <font size =\"-1\" face=\"arial,helvetica\">
                    <a href=\"$url\">$caption</a>
                </font>
            </td></tr></table>";
    }
    function listado_registros($registros_array,$id_edit){
        $total=0;
        echo "<table border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"1\" cellpadding=\"1\" align=\"center\" width=\"600\">
                <tr>
                    <th bgcolor=\"#669900\"><font color=\"white\" face=\"arial,helvetica\">
                <a href= index.php?ordena_por_campo=concepto&id=-1&buscar_texto=>Concepto</a></font></th>
                    <th bgcolor=\"#669900\"><font color=\"white\" face=\"arial,helvetica\">
                <a href= index.php?ordena_por_campo=fecha&id=-1&buscar_texto=>Fecha</a></font></th>
                    <th bgcolor=\"#669900\"><font color=\"white\" face=\"arial,helvetica\">
                <a href= index.php?ordena_por_campo=importe&id=-1&buscar_texto=>Importe (€)</a></font></th>
                    <th bgcolor=\"#669900\" colspan=\"2\"><font color=\"white\" face=\"arial,helvetica\">Operaciones</font></th>
                </tr>";
        for($i=0;$i<sizeof($registros_array);$i++){
            if($id_edit!=$registros_array[$i][0]){
                echo "<tr><td>".$registros_array[$i][1]."</td>
                    <td>".strftime('%d-%m-%Y',$registros_array[$i][2])."</td>
                    <td>".$registros_array[$i][3]."</td>
                    <td>".boton_ficticio("Editar","index_monedero.php?operacion=editar&nume=".$registros_array[$i][0])."</td>
                    <td>".boton_ficticio("Borrar","index_monedero.php?operacion=borrar&nume=".$registros_array[$i][0])."</td></tr>";
                    $total+=$registros_array[$i][3];
            }else{
                echo "<tr><form name=\"form3\" method=\"post\" action=\"index_monedero.php?operacion=modificar\">
                    <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"concepto\" size=\"10\" value=\"".$registros_array[$i][1]."\" maxlength=\"30\"></td>
                    <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"fecha\" size=\"25\" value=\"".$registros_array[$i][2]."\" maxlength=\"100\"></td>
                    <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"importe\" size=\"10\" value=\"".$registros_array[$i][3]."\" maxlength=\"30\"></td>
                    <td colspan=\"2\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"el_nume\" value=\"$id_edit\">
                    <input type=\"submit\" name=\"pulsa\" value=\"Modificar registro\"></td></form></tr>";
            }
        }
        echo "<tr><form name=\"form2\" method=\"post\" action=\"index_monedero.php?operacion=alta\">
                        <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"concepto\" size=\"10\" maxlength=\"30\"></td>
                            <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"fecha\" size=\"25\" maxlength=\"100\"></td>
                            <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"importe\" size=\"10\" maxlength=\"30\"></td>
                            <td colspan=\"2\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"pulsa\" value=\"Añadir registro\"></td>
                </form></tr>
            </table>";
    }
    class monedero{
        private $nombre_fichero="monedero.txt";
        public $numero_registros=0;
        function __construct(){
            if(!file_exists($this->nombre_fichero)){
                $id_fichero=@fopen($this->nombre_fichero,"w")
                    or die("<b>El fichero '$this->nombre_fichero' no se ha podido crear.</b><p>");
                fclose($id_fichero);
            }
        }
        function alta_registro($concepto,$fecha,$importe){
            $this->leer_registros();
            $id_fichero=@fopen($this->nombre_fichero,"a")
                    or die("<b>El fichero '$this->nombre_fichero' no se ha podido abrir.</b><p>");
            $nume=$this->numero_registros;
            $registro=array("nume"=>$nume,"concepto"=>$concepto,"fecha"=>$fecha,"importe"=>$importe);
            $registro_str="\n".implode("~",$registro);
            fputs($id_fichero,$registro_str);
            fclose($id_fichero);
        }
        function leer_registros(){
            $id_fichero=@fopen($this->nombre_fichero,"r")
                    or die("<b>El fichero '$this->nombre_fichero' no se ha podido abrir.</b><p>");
            rewind($id_fichero);
            $this->numero_registros=0;
            $registros=array();
            while(!feof($id_fichero)){
                $registro_str=trim(fgets($id_fichero));
                if($registro_str!=""){
                    array_push($registros,explode("~",$registro_str));
                    $this->numero_registros++;
                }
            }
            fclose($id_fichero);
            return $registros;
        }
        function modificar_registro($id_to_modi,$concepto,$fecha,$importe){
            $registros=$this->leer_registros();
            $id_fichero_temp=@fopen("basura.tmp","w")
            or die("<b>El fichero 'basura.tmp' no se ha podido abrir.</b><p>");
            for($i=0;$i<sizeof($registros);$i++){
                if ($registros[$i][0]==$id_to_modi){
                    $registros[$i][1]=$concepto;
                    $registros[$i][2]=$fecha;
                    $registros[$i][3]=$importe;
                }
                if($i>0) fputs($id_fichero_temp,"\n");
                $registro_str=implode("~",$registros[$i]);
                fputs($id_fichero_temp,$registro_str);
            }
            fclose($id_fichero_temp);
            unlink($this->nombre_fichero);
            rename("basura.tmp",$this->nombre_fichero);
        }
        function borrar_registro($id_to_del){
            $registros=$this->leer_registros();
            $id_fichero_temp=@fopen("basura.tmp","w")
                    or die("<b>El fichero 'basura.tmp' no se ha podido abrir.</b><p>");
            $j=0;
            for($i=0;$i<sizeof($registros);$i++){
                if($registros[$i][0]!=$id_to_del){
                    $registros[$i][0]=$j;
                    $registro_str=implode("~",$registros[$i]);
                    if($j>0) fputs($id_fichero_temp,"\n");
                    fputs($id_fichero_temp,$registro_str);
                    $j+=1;
                }
            }
            fclose($id_fichero_temp);
            unlink($this->nombre_fichero);
            rename("basura.tmp",$this->nombre_fichero);
        }
        function buscar($lo_q_busco){
            $id_fichero=@fopen($this->nombre_fichero,"r")
                    or die("<b>El fichero '$this->nombre_fichero' no se ha podido abrir.</b><p>");
            rewind($id_fichero);
            $registros=array();
            while(!feof($id_fichero)){
                $registro_str=trim(fgets($id_fichero));
                if($registro_str!=""){
                    $registro=explode("~",$registro_str);
                    if((stristr($registro[1],$lo_q_busco))||(stristr($registro[2],$lo_q_busco)))
                        array_push($registros,explode("~",$registro_str));
                }
            }
            fclose($id_fichero);
            return $registros;
        }
    }
?>
```

index-monedero.php (ver el penúltimo echo):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Actividad 1</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        <!--input{
            font-family:Arial,Helvetica;
            font-size:14;
            color:#000033;
            font-weight:normal;
            border-color:#999999;
            border-width:1;
            background-color:#FFFFFF;
            }-->
        </style>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#C0C0C0" link="white" vlink="white" alink="white">
        <table border="0" align="center" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" width="600" bgcolor="#669900">
            <tr>
                <td width=30><img src=cerdito.gif></td>
                <th align=center><font size="6" color="white" face="arial,helvetica">Monedero</font></th>
                <td width=30><img src=cerdito.gif></td>
            </tr>
        </table><p>
<?php
    require("monedero.php");
    $mi_monedero=new monedero();
    if(isset($_REQUEST["operacion"])){
        if($_REQUEST["operacion"]=="buscar"){
            if(($_POST["buscar_edit"])==""){
                echo "<center>No se ha introducido ninguna cadena!</center><p>";
            }else{
                echo "<center>Los registros que contienen '".$_POST["buscar_edit"]."' son:</center><p>";
                listado_registros($mi_monedero->buscar($_POST["buscar_edit"]),-1);
            }
        }elseif($_REQUEST["operacion"]=="editar"){
            listado_registros($mi_monedero->leer_registros(),$_REQUEST["nume"]);
        }else{
            if($_REQUEST["operacion"]=="alta"){
                if($_POST["concepto"]==""){
                    echo "<center>No se ha introducido ningún concepto!</center><p>";
                }else{
                    $mi_monedero->alta_registro($_POST["concepto"],$_POST["fecha"],$_POST["importe"]);
                    echo "<center>Se ha dado de alta correctamente el registro: ".$_POST["concepto"]."</center><p>";
                }
            }elseif($_REQUEST["operacion"]=="modificar"){
                if($_POST["concepto"]==""){
                    echo "<center>No se ha introducido ningún concepto!</center><p>";
                }else{
                    $mi_monedero->modificar_registro($_POST["el_nume"],$_POST["concepto"],$_POST["fecha"],$_POST["importe"]);
                    echo "<center>Se ha modificado correctamente el registro: ".$_POST["concepto"]."</center><p>";
                }
            }elseif($_REQUEST["operacion"]=="borrar"){
                $mi_monedero->borrar_registro($_REQUEST["nume"]);
                echo "<center>Se ha borrado correctamente el registro.</center><p>";
            }
            listado_registros($mi_monedero->leer_registros(),-1);
        }
    }else{
        listado_registros($mi_monedero->leer_registros(),-1);
    }
    echo "<center><p><table border=0 width=600>";
    echo "<tr><td colspan=\"2\"><hr></td></tr>";    
    echo "<tr><td valign=top align=right>
            <form method=\"post\" action=\"index_monedero.php?operacion=buscar\">
            <font size=\"-1\" face=\"arial,helvetica\">
            Buscar concepto:</font></td><td>";
    echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"buscar_edit\" size=\"20\">";
    echo "<INPUT type=\"submit\" name=\"buscar\" value=\"Buscar\">
                </form></td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td colspan=\"2\"><hr></td></tr>";
    echo "</table></center>";
    echo "<table border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"1\" cellpadding=\"1\" align=\"center\" width=\"600\">
            <tr><td><font size =\"-1\" face=\"arial,helvetica\">
            El nº de registros del monedero es: ".
            $mi_monedero->numero_registros."</left></font><p></td><td valign=top align=right>".
                boton_ficticio("Ver listado completo","index_monedero.php?operacion=listado")."
                </td></tr></table>";
    echo "<p><font color=red>El balance del monedero es de ".$total." €</font></p>";
    echo "<center><p>NOTA: es obligatorio rellenar el campo Concepto.</p></center>";
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema?

Comment: que no se como llamar a la variable $total desde el index a la clase

Comment: Una variable se llama muy fácil. En la función donde existe esa variable le pones un `return $total;`  y para llamarla desde otra parte haces: `$totalDesdeOtraParte=listado_registros($parametros);`